# how to update or refresh datagrid view connected with Ms-access in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

hi i have already connected the database in `Ms-access 2010(.mdb)` with `C#` then i want to display it in `datagrid` view , here is the code that i used to save or `insert the data`

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into VMS(PlateNo,JobCardNo,Model,DateIn,Status,PartList,PurchNo,PurchDate,Remark)" + "values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = mycon;
        mycon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.Close();
```

this works right, the problem is when i save new data it save in MS- access but it will not updated or displayed in the datagridview. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way To update your datagridview after inserting some data.

`Dataset sDs = new DataSet();`

`sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "T1");`

`sTable = sDs.Tables["T1"];`

`dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["T1"];`

Answer (score 0):

To update your datagridview after inserting some data , you should rebind your data grid view , some sudocode might be like this :

```
OledbConnection conn=new OledbConnection("your connectionstring");
OledbCommand comm=new OledbCommand("SELECT * FROM yourtablename",conn);
OledbDataAdapter da=new OledbDataAdatpter(comm);
Dataset ds=new dataSet();
conn.open();
da.Fill(ds,"T1");
datagridView.DataMember="T1";
datagridview.DataSource=ds;
conn.close();
```

NOTE: if your project is an asp.net project after assigning the datasource you have to write the method DataBind() to your datagridview this way :

```
datagridview.DataSource=ds;
datagridview.DataBind();
```

but in windows applications you don't have to perform the method DataBind()

please mark as answer if you It solved your problem

Comment: thanks khashayar but i think this works for connection with microsoft sql not for Ms-access would you show me this using oleDbcommand. best regards

Comment: @abelo I edited the code above for Oledb Provider class, Please mark as answer if It solved your problem ,this way othere peaople who have the same problem with find the answer here !